# Суть авторизации через соцсети

Tags: oauth

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с сутью авторизации через соцсети.

Я приведу пример для почты яндекса.

1. Раньше при обычной авторизации пользователю приходилось вводить пароль и логин на сайте почты яндекса. После этого он попадал в свой почтовый ящик
2. Сейчас существует возможность авторизоваться через соцсеть. Пользователь заходит на сайт почты яндекса, нажимает иконку (например, вконтакте), после этого всплывает окно, пользователь что-то подтвержает и после этого снова вводит пару логин/пароль

В чем смысл? Во втором описанном случае приходится совершать больше действий.

Answer (score 1):

Так вы можете быть **УЖЕ ЗАЛОГИНЕНЫМ** в вконтакте. И при нажатии на кнопку "войти через вконтакт" произойдёт обмен информацией между Яндексом и вконтактом (в данном случае не oauth, у вк свой протокол), Яндекс уверится что это именно Вы и вы сразу в почте. А действий придётся совершить значительно меньше. Разве что мигнёт промежуточное окно вконтакта с вопросом "можно ли предоставить информацию..."

В Яндексовском аккаунте можно привязать несколько учёток из других сетей, и как бы вы не входили, всё равно попадёте в свою почту.

А вообще,

> если вы активно пользуетесь интернетом, то вам наверняка приходится регистрироваться на разных сайтах и помнить множество логинов и паролей. Вместо этого вы можете использовать свою регистрацию на Гугле/Yahoo/вконтакте/одноглазниках/Яндексе/Фейсбуке/Твиттере (нужное подчеркнуть) в качестве единого логина, который можно использовать для входа на самые разные сайты

Comment: Спасибо. Насчет множества паролей согласен. Но первую часть ответа не понял. Что значит уже залогинен? Когда я обычным способом авторизуюсь, то ставлю галочку у "запомнить меня". После этого как только загружаю страницу яндекса, сразу попадаю в свою почту. И без всяких промежуточных окон. На большинстве сайтов такая же система.

Comment: так на 2й вопрос - ответ в первой строке ответа.

Comment: вы открыли браузер, в котором вы вчера заходили на facebook и поставили там галочку "запомнить меня", т.е. сечас вас facebook помнит, соответственно при входе на Яндекс вы нажимаете кнопку facebook и проходите в свою почту уже *без* ввода пароля - вот вам и отсутствие лишних шагов